# Do find command options "-o=r" and "/o=r" give the same results?

Tags: find

I'm studying `find` command options.

Will

```
find . -perm -o=r
```

and

```
find . -perm /o=r
```

give the same results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those are the same. The difference comes when there is more than one permission listed, in which case, `-` will require **all** of the permissions be set on the files it lists, while `/` will require **any** of the permissions be set on the files it lists.

For example, `-perm -o=rw` will find files which others can both read and write, while `-perm /o=rw` will find files which others can read as well as files which others can write.

See the `man find` section on the `-perm` option.

Comment: Thanks. So, find command doesn't care about additional permissions on both of the cases, - and /. They only care about only what is on the perm options, right?

Comment: @Smile That's right.